# Convergence of points under the Mandelbrot iterated equation

Tags: combinatorics, complex-numbers, fractals

I was looking at $z_n=z_n^2+z_0$ and I realized I didn't know what convergence actually looked like, even in real numbers.  I picked a really easy number, -0.5, to see what it did.  It approached a number I don't know :(

A wolfram alpha widget helped me out here.  It appears to converge to something like -0.366025403784
https://www.desmos.com/calculator/2op8thgknv

[image]

In other words, I'm wondering if there's a closed-form way to write: $$((((x^2+x)^2+x)^2+x)^2+x...)$$ for $x=-.05

Comment: This  iteration converges to one of the solutions of $z = z^2 + z_0$, if it converges at all. For  $z_0 = -1/2$, it converges to $(1 - \sqrt{3})/2$.

Comment: @HansEngler OHH thank you.  We can say that because as the number of iterations approaches infinity, $z_n$ approaches $z_{n+1}$ (given convergence)? Or something like that?

Comment: As $n \to \infty$, both $z_n$ and $z_{n+1}$ have the same limit.

Answer (score 1):

The behavior and convergence (or not) of $z_{n+1}=z_n^2+z_0$ very much depends on $z_0$. In 1D, see the [Logistic map](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Logistic_map). There is a close relationship with the Mandelbrot set:

[image]
[image from [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mandelbrot_set#Basic_properties)]